# Azure returns valid access token with an invalid client secret

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Azure access token is returned even with an invalid secret when run in a multithreaded environment.

I've got an integration test that checks to see that an invalid client secret won't pass when getting an Azure access token.

When run in isolation the test passes every time, meaning that an invalid client secret does not return an Azure access token.

However, when run with other integration tests (on multiple threads) this function returns an access token even with an obviously invalid client secret.

I don't see any legitimate reason this would be a cached token for the client id even when specifying a totally invalid client secret.

Note, this behavior does not happen when the client id is invalid.

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

```
    private async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
        var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

        Debug.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
        Debug.WriteLine(clientId);
        Debug.WriteLine(clientSecret);
        Debug.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

The debug output is

```
Debug Trace:
----------------------------------
<...client id...>
invalid secret
<...valid token...>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your cache still has a valid access token in the cache. ADAL checks the cache first and returns the access token if still valid (not expired).  Token cache pivots on client_id as one of the dimensions of the key, so invalid client_id fails as expected. To force the library to use the secret and make a network call, you must delete the token from the cache

Comment: That is interesting that it doesn't care about the secret when hitting the cache. Isn't that a security risk when separate threads may be introduced from an external source and they have access to the client id but not the secret? It sounds like I need to find a way to flush the cache, or exercise more control over it.

Comment: Based on my understanding, the web app which have secret is a confidential app. It means that we should ensure it runs in safe environment, and the secret always provide from your app(et. from server-side) to prove its identity. Would you minding share more info in your scenario about using the incorrect secret?

Comment: I'm not sure I have a scenario where this would be a problem yet, but it is important to understand how this is working so that I don't introduce a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clear client credential token like below. This AuthenticationContext cache the credentials. clear them before checking another pair of keys.

```
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0");
        if (authenticationContext?.TokenCache.Count > 0)
        {
            authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();
        }
```